# 'Spreadsheet' data model with Ember-Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js

I am trying to represent a 'spreadsheet' like data model using ember-data.

The main reason for this is that I want to load .CSV data into this model structure and view the data from both column- and row-oriented perspectives.

I do not know ahead of time what the content of the .CSV will be so a row-based data model with column names would not work, as I understand it.

I have four main models:

```
App.DataSet = DS.Model.extend({
  name: attr('string'),
  columns: hasMany('column', {async:true}),
  rows: hasMany('row', {async:true})
});

App.Column = DS.Model.extend({
  dataSet: belongsTo('data-set'),
  name: attr(),
  cells: hasMany('cells',{async:true})
});

App.Row = DS.Model.extend({
  dataSet: belongsTo('data-set'),  
  cells: hasMany('cell',{async:true})
});

App.Cell = DS.Model.extend({
  row: belongsTo('row'),
  column: belongsTo('column'),
  value: attr()
});
```

I have created some FIXTURE data for the model and it seems to work (although any suggestions for a better approach are welcomed!).

I am now trying to display the data in a table. My index controller is an ArrayController which looks for 'DataSet's from the store. My template looks like:

```
<div>
  <h1>Data/h1>
  <ul>
  {{#each d in model}}
  <li>
    {{d.name}}
    <br>

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>{{#each col in d.columns}}<td>{{col.name}}</td>{{/each}}</tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {{#each row in d.rows}}
          <tr>
            {{#each cell in row.cells}}<td>{{cell.column.id}}&nbsp;{{cell.value}}</td>{{/each}}
          </tr>
        {{/each}}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </li>
  {{/each}}
  <ul>
</div>
```

When this is rendered, I find that for some rows the cells are correctly ordered with respect to the columns but in others they are not. I am including a screenshot to make this point clear.

[image: ember table]

How do I render each cell in correct column order?

Thanks,

Michael

Comment: Without seeing your fixture data its hard to say. If you are relying on JavaScript object property/key ordering then that could explain the issue as JavaScript does not define any ordering for object properties.

Comment: I would guess that your row.cells is not maintaining the same order as your d.columns.  You need to sort row.cells before you use it, according to the value in cell.column, such that the cells end up in the same order as d.columns.  This may require defining another property in an item controller for the rows, that takes care of the sorting, and using that property in the each instead of row.cells.